# Protection from Format String Vulnerability

Tags: string, format

What exactly is a "Format String Vulnerability" in a Windows System, how does it work, and how can I protect against it?

Comment: Well, knowing how to attack helps in knowing how to defend/avoid the vulnerability. That's the idea of publicly disclose such vulnerabilities/exploits.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe I misread the tone of the question, thanks to ctacke for editing it.  I've posted an answer assuming it deserves the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I've edited the question, so it's now really asking the same information, but in language that is more appropriate and SO-friendly.  I'm not certain of the original author's intent, but if it's other than what I changed it to, it was destined for deletion anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A format string attack, at its simplest, is this:

```
char buffer[128];
gets(buffer);
printf(buffer);
```

There's a buffer overflow vulnerability in there as well, but the point is this: you're passing untrusted data (from the user) to `printf` (or one of its cousins) that uses that argument as a format string.

That is: if the user types in "%s", you've got an information-disclosure vulnerability, because `printf` will treat the user input as a format string, and will attempt to print the next thing on the stack as a string. It's as if your code said `printf("%s");`. Since you didn't pass any other arguments to `printf`, it'll display something arbitrary.

If the user types in "%n", you've got a potential elevation of privilege attack (at least a denial of service attack), because the %n format string causes `printf` to write the number of characters printed so far to the next location on the stack. Since you didn't give it a place to put this value, it'll write to somewhere arbitrary.

This is all bad, and is one reason why you should be extremely careful when using `printf` and cousins.

What you should do is this:

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

This means that the user's input is never treated as a format string, so you're safe from that particular attack vector.

In Visual C++, you can use the `__Format_string` annotation to tell it to validate the arguments to `printf`. `%n` is disallowed by default. In GCC, you can use `__attribute__(__printf__)` for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In this pseudo code the user enters some characters to be printed, like "hello"

```
string s=getUserInput();
write(s)
```

That works as intended. But since the write can format strings, for example

```
int i=getUnits();
write("%02d units",i);
```

outputs:  "03 units". What about if the user in the first place wrote "%02d"... since there is no parameters on the stack, something else will be fetched. What that is, and if that is a problem or not depends on the program.

An easy fix is to tell the program to output a string:

```
write("%s",s);
```

or use another method that don't try to format the string:

```
output(s);
```

a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack) to wikipedia with more info.